# redirect U-Boot Console to UART4 in rpi cm4 board

Tags: uart, u-boot

I am using Raspberry pi CM4 for my project.  The Hardware is designed in such a way that i need to redirect all the debug messages coming through serial UART0 to UART4.

I Use U-Boot as a boot loader as it is one of the requirement and the problem is that I am not able to redirect the u-boot console to UART4.  I able to see the debug messages through the default UART0 port.

I suppose that just by changing the Base address of the UART port things will come into place.  I did some code walk through but was not able to find the needed thing. Where can I find UART config code in U-Boot source?

Has anyone faced a similar issue and found solution? Pls Help.  Thanks

The config.txt looks like this:

```
arm_64bit=1
disable_splash=1
#start_debug=1
kernel=u-boot.bin
enable_uart=1
disable_overscan=1
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=uart4
```