# Redirect U-Boot console to UART2 in RPi 4B

Tags: pi-4, uart, u-boot

This is similar to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124886/redirect-u-boot-console-to-uart4-in-rpi-cm4-board), but for different hardware and with some things already tried. My ultimate goal is to have bluetooth on UART0 and debug on UART2.

I use RPi 4B and need to redirect U-Boot console to UART2. My current setup:

1. I configured `force_eeprom_read=0` and `disable_poe_fan=1` in my config.txt as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-pizerow-pi4-or-later-models/107780).
2. For now I also have `dtoverlay=disable-bt` and `enable_uart=1` in config.txt.
3. I configured `dtoverlay=uart2` in my config.txt
4. I prepared (and applied in config.txt) an overlay to pick uart2 in /chosen node:

   ```
   /dts-v1/;
   /plugin/;

   /{
           compatible = "brcm,bcm2711";

           fragment@0 {   
                   target-path = "/chosen";
                   __overlay__ {
                           /* uart2 */
                           stdout-path = "serial@7e201400:115200n8";
                   };     
           };
   };
   ```
5. When I boot the device in this configuration, U-Boot console still points to UART0.
6. In U-Boot prompt I check serial configuration using `coninfo`:

   ```
   U-Boot> coninfo
   List of available devices:
   serial@7e201000 00000007 IO 
   serial   00000003 IO stdin stdout stderr
   ```
7. I can also investigate the /chosen node of device tree:

   ```
   U-Boot> fdt addr ${fdt_addr}
   U-Boot> fdt list /chosen
   chosen {
           ranges;
           #size-cells = <0x00000001>;
           #address-cells = <0x00000001>;
           compatible = "simple_bus";
           kaslr-seed = <0xb6f21e2c 0x0dbb17ef>;
           stdout-path = "serial@7e201400:115200n8";
           rpi-boardrev-ext = <0x00000000>;
           bootargs = "...";
           framebuffer@3eaf5000 {
           };
           bootloader {
           };
   };
   ```

   The overlay applied correctly, as I now have stdout-path set to the desired UART.
8. Further investigating the device tree:

   ```
   U-Boot> fdt list /soc/serial@7e201400
   serial@7e201400 {
           pinctrl-0 = <0x000000a0>;
           pinctrl-names = "default";
           compatible = "arm,pl011", "arm,primecell";
           reg = <0x7e201400 0x00000200>;
           interrupts = <0x00000000 0x00000079 0x00000004>;
           clocks = <0x00000007 0x00000013 0x00000007 0x00000014>;
           clock-names = "uartclk", "apb_pclk";
           arm,primecell-periphid = <0x00241011>;
           status = "okay";
           phandle = <0x000000b2>;
   };
   ```

   This shows that the uart2 overlay was applied correctly. However, this UART is not even shown in the coninfo list.

What do I miss here?

---

I found the first error: the `stdout-path` should be defined as full path, like this: `/soc/serial@7e201400:115200n8`.

However, when I fix this, the device does not boot at all. This is verified by the ACT LED not blinking and ethernet port LEDs not blinking.

When I disable my overlay that updates `/chosen` by commenting it out in config.txt, the device boots normally.